# az cli command for the updating the security principle is not working

Tags: azure, azure-cli

its very strange that Microsoft document is not clear about the step to create a new ACL entry in the existing blobs existing directory without modifying any existing ACL entry.
My aim here is to create new Security principal on timely requirement and also sometimes need to update permission of existing security principal.

Not understading, how to achieve the below point mentioned in the docs.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-acl-cli#:~:text=To%20update%20an%20ACL%2C%20create%20a%20new%20ACL%20object%20with%20the%20ACL%20entry%20that%20you%20want%20to%20update%2C%20and%20then%20use%20that%20object%20in%20update%20ACL%20operation.%20Do%20not%20get%20the%20existing%20ACL%2C%20just%20provide%20ACL%20entries%20to%20be%20updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-acl-cli#:%7E:text=To%20update%20an%20ACL%2C%20create%20a%20new%20ACL%20object%20with%20the%20ACL%20entry%20that%20you%20want%20to%20update%2C%20and%20then%20use%20that%20object%20in%20update%20ACL%20operation.%20Do%20not%20get%20the%20existing%20ACL%2C%20just%20provide%20ACL%20entries%20to%20be%20updated).

"To update an ACL, create a new ACL object with the ACL entry that you want to update, and then use that object in update ACL operation. Do not get the existing ACL, just provide ACL entries to be updated."

So what I tried is below

```
az storage fs access set --permissions "user:objctidxxxxxxxxxx:rwx" -p /testdata01blob01directory01/testdatablob01directory01sub01 -f  testdatablob01 --account-name testdata0
```

I am getting below error, tried with different syntaxes but no luck

```
(InvalidPermission) The permission value is invalid.
RequestId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "To update an ACL, create a new ACL object with the ACL entry that you
> want to update, and then use that object in update ACL operation. Do
> not get the existing ACL, just provide ACL entries to be updated."

The above paragraph, describes that if you want to changes the permission of the acl it is suggesting to create a new acl with required permissions instead of using the existing acl permissions & updating it.

> My aim here is to create new Security principal on timely requirement
> you should have to use update acl inorder to create a new service principal & add the permissions to it .

As per the documentation ,If you want to change the permission level of a security principal or add a new security principal to the ACL without affecting other existing entries, you should *update* the ACL instead.

> az storage fs access set --permissions "user:objctidxxxxxxxxxx:rwx" -p
> /testdata01blob01directory01/testdatablob01directory01sub01 -f
> testdatablob01 --account-name testdata0
>
> (InvalidPermission) The permission value is invalid.
> RequestId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

You need to use `--acl` flag instead of `--persmission` in the above cmdlet  if you want to update the acl permission for a particular blob under a particular directory.

- if you are using the auth-mode as key you need to pass the storage account key in your cmdlet.

```
 az storage fs access set --acl "user:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:rwx" -p <directorypath>  -f <filesystemname> --account-name <datalakestorageaccount> --auth-mode key --account-key <storage-account-key>
```

Here is the sample output for reference :

[image]

- if you are using auth-mode as login, as mentioned in the documentation  you need have `storage blob data owner` role

```
  az storage fs access set --acl "user:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:rwx" -p <directorypath>  -f <filesystemname> --account-name <datalakestorageaccount> --auth-mode login
```

Here is the sample output for reference :

[image]

You can refer this documentation for more [sample examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/access?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_fs_access_set-examples) & usage of `az storage fs access set`  cmdlet.

Comment: but if i use this command "az storage fs access set --acl "user:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:rwx" -p <directorypath>  -f <filesystemname> --account-name <datalakestorageaccount> --auth-mode login" this is replacing other security principla as well.

Comment: so no option to just to add or change a new security principle alone to the existing ACL, without modifying any values

Comment: and "--persmission", this flag is only meant for changing permission of owning users,group and others and not for any additional users?

Comment: As per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/access?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_fs_access_set-optional-parameters) using ``az storage fs access set --permission rwx------ --owner/group <objectid> `` allows only [owner](https://i.imgur.com/QyF8GiY.png) or group level service principal permission update instead of recreating .

Comment: if you want to update the particular acl permission of a service principal you can use this [update-recurssive](https://i.imgur.com/1Ax6i3f.png) cmdlet 

az storage fs access update-recursive --acl "user:<objectid>:r-x" -p <directorypath> -f <filesystemname> --account-name <datalakename> --auth-mode login

Comment: Great.. thanks.. Not sure how we can create the ACL at root level as well since its required to give execute permission for any kind of accesses, But I could see the AZ commands to give in parent folder and directory level. Not sure how to give the access in container level first

Comment: az storage fs access update-recursive --acl "user:<objectid>:r-x" -p <directorypath> -f <filesystemname> --account-name <datalakename> --auth-mode login works for me, but taking hours to get it done for some existing filesysyems, and the operation getting timed out. So is there any way to overcome that? or instead of assigning recursively, can we update the access only to the path which we are passing ?